# Minute in bootstrap datetimepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using `bootstrap-datetimepicker-0.0.11` on my input type text element.

Date picking works fine but `minute` functionality is not working.

When `incrementing` minute arrow, nothing happens, and on `decrementing` hour values gets decremented instead of minute value.

Here's my html snippet:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="date_from">Date From *</label>
     <input type="text" readonly name="date_from" class="form-control date_from" id="date_from" placeholder="Enter training start date">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="date_to">Date To *</label>
     <input type="text" readonly name="date_to" class="form-control date_to" id="date_to" placeholder="Enter training end date">
</div>
```

And here's datetimepicker initialization:

```
$('.date_from, .date_to').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'});
```

Anyone happens to know why the plugin is working in unexpected manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this datetime format:

```
$('.date_from, .date_to').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii'});
```

where `'M'` and `'m'` are the same so you were probably confused by using the month value instead of the minute value.  The minute value is declared by `'i'`

See more information here: https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

Comment: This solved my issue. It was such a silly issue I can't help but laugh. Thank you.